# Scala - Why does my for loop not return?

Tags: scala, for-loop, return

I'm attempting to perform some retry logic with Scala. For the sake of providing a MRE, I have replaced the exception-throwing object with `Y`. When running `X.main`. I expect to see this print two failure messages, then one success message, but it appears that the `return` statement is effectively acting as a no-op, and I'm seeing 3 success messages.

I realize this isn't idiomatic Scala and there are plenty of other ways to accomplish this, but is there no way to return from within a `for` loop in Scala? If not, why is that?

```
object X {
  def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {

    val y = new Y()

    for ( i <- 1 to 5 ) {
      try {
        y.doSomething()
        return
      } catch {
        case e : Throwable =>
          if ( i == 5 ) {
            throw e
          }
      }
    }
  }
}

class Y {
  var counter = 0

  def doSomething() : Unit = {
    if ( counter < 2 ) {
      println("Tried to do something, but failed")
      counter += 1
      throw new RuntimeException
    }
    println("Did something")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return` is even more *weird* than you thought, not just "non-idiomatic". 
It actually *throws an exception*. Your `catch` clause catches and swallows it. That's why it "acts as no-op".

Don't do this. Please.

But, if you insist, do, at least `catch { case NonFatal(e) =>` instead as suggested in the comment - that would let through the exceptions thrown by `return`.

Comment: Also, use `NonFatal` to avoid catching the `ControlThrowable` that `returns` throws. See https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/util/control/NonFatal$.html

Comment: Thanks! And in regards to your "don't do this" comment - I wasn't actually planning on it. I was more so just wanting to understand how `return` behaved under the sheets. I rewrote this using tail recursion before even posting this question.